# Getting Date C#/SQL Server Datetime to work with HTML 5 Datefield and jquery DatePicker

Tags: jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

How can return the date in the proper format for HTML5, ISO-8601, from a datetime type in MVC4 razor view which will work with both HTML5 datefield and allow for jquery datepicker for non-html5 browsers.

I used [this post](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/using-the-html5-and-jquery-ui-datepicker-popup-calendar-with-aspnet-mvc/using-the-html5-and-jquery-ui-datepicker-popup-calendar-with-aspnet-mvc-part-4) as my basis and went to the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XSTK8/15/) as referenced in the article.  I could only get the jquery date picker or the html5 datepicker to work not both.

I get it close when using the jsfiddle javascript and modify my date.cshtml file to 
@model Nullable

```
 @{
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
    if (Model != null)
    {
       dt  = (System.DateTime) Model;

    }
    @Html.TextBox("", String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", dt), new { @class = "datefield", type = "date"  })
}
```

With this the HTML5 datepicker works but for a date of 2012-12-28 the data field in non-html5 displays 0/28/2013.  When I change the format to MM/dd/yyyy the HTML5 datepicker stops working and displays the default mm/dd/yyyy text.  Anyway to get them both to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue was with the javascript in the jsfiddle.  I did some logging to the console and found out everything was fine until the new date was getting created.  Since I couldn't figure out why the date was getting set to the next year I posted [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17491166/jquery-change-date-fromat-from-8601-to-usa-standard).  When you do a new date you have to subtract one for the month.

Final Code is here:

Model:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)] 
public DateTime? ArrivalScene { get; set; }
```

Date.cshtml:

```
@model Nullable<DateTime>

 @{
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
    if (Model != null)
    {
       dt  = (System.DateTime) Model;

    }

    @Html.TextBox("", String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", dt), new { @class = "datefield", type = "date"  })
}
```

DatePickerReady.js:

```
$(function () {
    var datefields = $("input[type='date']");


    if (!Modernizr.inputtypes.date) {
        datefields
            .datepicker()
            .each(function () {
                 //Turn ISO 8601 date string into US date string
                var dateParts = this.value.split("-"),
                    date = $.map(dateParts, function (el) {
                        return !isNaN(parseInt(el, 10)) ? el : null;
                    }).length === 3
                        ? new Date(dateParts[0], dateParts[1] -1, dateParts[2])
                        : null;

                this.type = "text";
                this.value = !date ? "" :
                    (date.getMonth()+1) + "/" +
                    date.getDate() + "/" +
                    date.getFullYear();
            });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had success using a data annotation in my model:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[Display(Name = "The Date")]
public DateTime? TheDate { get; set; }
```

and the [JQueryUIHelpers](http://nuget.org/packages/jQueryUIHelpers.Mvc4/) Package in my view:

```
@Html.JQueryUI().DatepickerFor(model => model.TheDate, new {type="date"})
```

Comment: So this will allow the HTML5 datepicker to work on html5 browsers and it takes care of the different format?

Comment: @Xaxum It should, but you'll need to perform an initial js check, perhaps using modernizr, to determine if the browser supports the HTML5 date picker. If it does, you don't want to trigger the date picker for jquery UI.