# Jquery change date fromat from 8601 to usa standard

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have this code from [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XSTK8/15/).

```
$(function() {
    var datefields = $("input[type='date']");
    // Log starting markup
    datefields.each(function() {
        var $el = $(this), $parent = $el.parent();
        $parent.next().text($parent.html());

    });

    if (!Modernizr.inputtypes.date) {
        datefields    
            .datepicker()
            .each(function() {
                // Turn ISO 8601 date string into US date string
                var dateParts = this.value.split("-"),
                    date = $.map(dateParts, function (el) {
                        return !isNaN(parseInt(el, 10)) ? el : null;
                    }).length === 3
                        ? new Date(dateParts[0], dateParts[1], dateParts[2])
                        : null;
                this.type = "text";
                this.value = !date ? "" :
                    date.getMonth() + "/" +
                    date.getDate() + "/" +
                    date.getFullYear();
            });
    }

    // Log final results
    datefields.each(function() {
        var $el = $(this), $parent = $el.parent();
        $parent.next().next().text($el.val())
        $parent.next().next().next().text($el.attr("value"));
        $parent.next().next().next().next().text($el.prop("value"));
        $parent.next().next().next().next().next().text(this.getAttribute("value"));
    });
});
```

I can't figure out how to get it to properly convert the date into MM/dd/yyyy format.  With a date of 2012-12-28 it puts in a date of 0/28/2013 for non-html5 date browsers.  It works fine for html5 browsers.  If I substitute in the date.getmonth()... etc with a string of the date in correct format it displays properly.  So I know it has to do with the values getMonth() and getFullYear() are returning.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getMonth()` in JavaScript is zero-based. You need to decrease the value by 1 when creating it:

```
    ? new Date(dateParts[0], parseInt(dateParts[1]) - 1, dateParts[2])
```

and then add 1 to the value for displaying it again:

```
            this.value = !date ? "" :
                (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" +
                date.getDate() + "/" +
                date.getFullYear();
```

See [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) about `getMonth()` on the Mozilla Development Network.

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize that.  However, my original date has a month of 12 and it is outputting 0 so adding 1 still only gets me January instead of the expected December.

Comment: You probably need to initialise the month part of the Date object with `parseInt(dateParts[1]) - 1` instead, then. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Do you know why you need to do a -1?  When I log the dateparts to the console I get the correct values for each part.  However, when the date gets created it goes to January.  If I do the -1 as you indicate it gives the correct date but I don't understand why the -1 is needed when I do parsInt on '12' it should give me 12 not 13.

Comment: Dates in JavaScript have the month based around 0 being January, all the way through to 11 being December. When the month was set to 12, that was interpreted as being the January of the following year.

Comment: Sorry, guess I need to clarify further.  It looks to me when you create a new date in javascript you pass in the actual month you want.  So if you create new Date(2012, 12, 28) it should create 12/28/2012.  So when I pass it the dateparts with those values I shouldn't need to - 1.  I don't get why you would need to pass new Date(2012, 11, 28) to get the date 12/28/2014.  I understand that getMonth() will return 11 but the initializer doesn't document that it needs a 0 based month, that I can find.

Comment: Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date - "Month: Integer value representing the month, beginning with 0 for January to 11 for December."